# php return array from function returns NULL

Tags: php, arrays, function, return, hierarchy

Still just learning PHP so sorry if this is stupid!! I have a function that loops through a mysql adjacency table. I would like to return this as an array. It seems fine, in that if when I return in the function I do print_r($path); where $path is the array inside the function, the array is printed as I want it.

The problem is I cannot see why I cannot access it via

```
$patharray = functioncalled($vars);
```

I have tried using return $path; and also just `print_r` in the array, but it keeps returning `NULL`.

```
function getParPath($mysqli, $showpar, $path) {
    // Get Parent Path
    $query ="select loc_id, loc_name, loc_parent from locations where loc_id = ? LIMIT 0,1";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query)) {

        /* pass parameters to query */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $showpar);

        /* run the query on the database */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* store result */
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        /* assign variable for each column to store results in */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $loc_id, $loc_name, $loc_parent);

        /* fetch values */
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

            $path[] = $loc_name;

            if ($loc_parent !='0'){
                getParPath($mysqli, $loc_parent, $path);
            }
            if ($loc_parent =='0'){
                $path = array_reverse($path);
                return $path; // uncommented per answers below.
                //print_r($path); //commented out per answers below.
            }

        }
    }
}

$patharray = getParPath($mysqli, $showcld, $path);
//print_r(getParPath($mysqli, $showcld, $path)); // removed per answers below
var_dump($patharray); //removed echo per answers below
exit;
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BuildingA
    [1] => FloorA
    [2] => RoomA
)
Array
(
    [0] => BuildingA
    [1] => FloorA
    [2] => RoomA
)
NULL
```

So as you can see from the last line there, the array `$patharray` I set to the function call is `NULL`. And that if I try to `print_r` inside the function, an array is printed, and if I try to `print_r` the function directly, it returns an array. But not into an object I can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `return $path;` not just `echo` or `print_r`.

```
$path = array_reverse($path);
return $path;  //Uncomment this line
//print_r($path); //Comment out this line
```

Also you need to change this, you weren't setting $path equal to the results:

```
if ($loc_parent !='0'){
    $path = getParPath($mysqli, $loc_parent, $path);
}
```

Also get rid of the if test because it will keep running until it gets to the bottom then you need to return.

```
if ($loc_parent !='0'){
    $path = getParPath($mysqli, $loc_parent, $path);
}
$path = array_reverse($path);
return $path;
```

Comment: Lol you even have it in there it is just commented out.

Comment: Thanks-but... I did have this in originally and it didn't work, this is why I commented it out and put print_r in instead, so I could see what what actually the output of the function.
Is there something else wrong?

Comment: If I comment the print_r and uncomment the return line, it just results in NULL

Comment: Why do you have `echo vardump()` `vardump()` echos itself you don't need `echo`. Also comment out the `print_r(getParPath($mysqli, $showcld, $path));` this is redundant and makes debugging harder.

Comment: I didn't know that about vardump thanks, I removed the print_r now, I have updated the code in the question to as it is per your comments.

It just returns NULL

Comment: I added in $path = .. as you updated answer, but it still returns NULL.

If I put the print_r($path) inside the function above the return I can see that it is printing the array. I've removed the print_r again ( was just testing)

Comment: See answer you need to get rid of the other if test. Otherwise nothing will ever be returned.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean? 
There are two if tests, the first checks if the location has a parentID, if it does then it runs again, and the second is when it is the root/top level/there are no parents, which is where it then returns the array. If I print at this point I can see the array is as expected. If I change the print_r to return I get NULL.

Comment: Yes but you are returning the array to another instance of the function being ran, not to the first instance of the function being ran. Therefore your first instance will never return anything. Only the last level.